# SQL repeat events by timer

Tags: sql, mysql, timer, scheduled-tasks

I want that a column of my database, composed by float random numbers, change every x seconds determined by a timer.
I read about Schedule Tasks Events but i can't work it.
Please help

Comment: I can't think of a good reason to do this! Why don't you generate the random numbers in the client, or in the query? What is the purpose of the column

Comment: Although I also can't think of a reason to want to be able to do this, I wouldn't classify it as, "Not a real question"

Comment: I have to simulate a financial market like wall street, so numbers have to change into the database. 
I have found the way to do it with the following SQL statement which increase by 1 the value of the actual every 2 seconds for 9 hours:

  CREATE EVENT addTimer
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 SECOND
  STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 9 HOUR
  DO
  UPDATE prova.prova SET actual = actual + 1

Comment: Numbers on Wall Street don't change - new numbers are added for new times.  If you have a timestamp column, you could get the latest quote for a stock ticker.  This would bemore realistic.

Comment: the wall street was just an example....
I am testing cpu and ram usage because i want to know if my application isn't too "heavy" for a "normal" notebook; i think that is an heavy test so i want to do that.
I want them to change dynamically into an advanced data grid without collapsing the tree view structure, so ONLY actual, which is a field of a table composed by 5 fields, have to change.

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm only familiar with sql server, but could you set up a stored proc with an infinite loop and a wait?

Comment: i've solved the problem with the sql statement commented up
i have created a client with Adobe Air which displays in an AdvancedDataGrid with treeview the database content; if i refresh the database, the tree structure collapse, so i want only some fields of the grid refresh.

Answer (score 1):

The following statement solve part of the problem, i hope it will be useful for others users:

```
CREATE EVENT addTimer 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 SECOND 
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 9 HOUR 
DO 
UPDATE prova.prova SET actual = actual + 1
```